# Better approach for multiple if else statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a program that takes in 3 numbers (feet, inches, sixteenths) then multiplies them by `x`. Upon starting to write the output part, I ran into needing:

```
if (sixteenths4<16) {
    sixteenths5=sixteenths4;
    inches6=0;
}else if (16<=sixteenths4) {
    sixteenths5=sixteenths4-16;
    inches6=1;
}else if (32<=sixteenths4) {
    sixteenths5=sixteenths4-32;
    inches6=2;
}else if (48<=sixteenths4) {
    sixteenths5=sixteenths4-48;
    inches6=3;
} else {
    sixteenths5=sixteenths4-64;
    inches6=4;
    }
```

I realize the last else is redundant as it will never happen. My issue is that since the total sixteenths could exceed 4-5 hundred, that would be a lot of `if else` blocks. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: inches=sixteenths/16 sixteenths=sixteenths%16

Comment: `switch` statements wont work very well when if statements do not use `==` operator (or equals).

Comment: You should post complete code

Answer (score 4):

Remive all the if/else statements and use integer arithmetic instead.

This is equivalent code for all your code:

```
sixteenths5 = sixteenths4 % 16;
inches6 = sixteenths4 / 16;
```

Comment: @wahoozie These two lines are the EXACT equivalent of the block you posted.

You're basically want to store a value 0-15 in the `sixteenths5` variable. Using the modulus operation, you are basically dividing `sixteenths4` by 16, but storing the remainder in `sixteenths5`. Since this operations *DOES NOT* modify `sixteenths4`, you can use it to divide by 16 and store the quotient. Since you are using `int` the result is truncated. Therefore, values 0-15 will result in 0 stored in `inches6`, 16-31 will result in 1, and so on.

Comment: Excellent answer, I should have titled this, "when to use the remainder operator." I am new to programming, thanks for the info.